# How do I check if a Sequelize JSONB field of type object has a key of a specific name?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

How do I check if a Sequelize (v6.21.4) JSONB field (that is always of type object and has `defaultValue: {}` ) has a key of a specific name?

The field, named "items", is defined as the following: (full Model included at the bottom of the post for reference)

```js
    items: {
      type: DataTypes.JSONB,
      defaultValue: {}
    }
```

I'm currently using #findAll and calling Array#filter manually to resolve the query like the following:

```js
  const traders = (await MarketTraderConfig.findAll({
    where: {
      MarketServerId: id
    },
    include: [{
      model: MarketTraderMap,
      include: [{
        model: MarketTraderZoneConfig
      }]
    }]
  })).filter((t) => t.categories.find((cat) => cat === categoryConfig.categoryName
    // Check if the items object has a key named ${item}
    || [item] in t.items)
  );
```

I personally thought JSONB was directly supported in Sequelize `FindOptions` and thought I could do the following:

```js
    where: {
      MarketServerId: id,
      [Op.or]: [
        { categories: { [Op.startsWith]: categoryConfig.categoryName } },
        { items: { [item]: { [Op.ne]: null } } }
      ]
   }
```

But that resulted in the following error:

```
parent: error: operator does not exist: character varying[] ~~ unknown,
original: error: operator does not exist: character varying[] ~~ unknown,
hint: 'No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.',
```

Which I don't really understand why that's happening

My MarketTraderConfig model for reference:

```js
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class MarketTraderConfig extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate (models) {
      MarketTraderConfig.belongsTo(models.MarketServer);
      MarketTraderConfig.hasOne(models.MarketTraderMap);
    }
  }
  MarketTraderConfig.init({
    m_Version: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    traderName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    displayName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    minRequiredReputation: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    maxRequiredReputation: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    traderIcon: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    currencies: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
        isLowercase: true
      }
    },
    categories: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      allowNull: false
    },
    // #items example:
    // {
    //   helmet: 1,
    //   boots: 1,
    //   item3: 0,
    //   className: 3
    // }
    items: {
      type: DataTypes.JSONB,
      defaultValue: {}
    },
    /// ... virtuals
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'MarketTraderConfig'
  });
  return MarketTraderConfig;
};
```